# How to create "fluid grid with equal percentage margin on child & parent element of a grid" using sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

How to create "fluid grid with equal percentage margin on child & parent element of a grid" using sass?? check the below image..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rde8.png

I created a fluid grid using sass. But the gap between child column(grey box) not same as parent elements. How to create a grid system using sass where child gap equal to parent gap(as shown in second image)??

UPDATE
    ===============
    check this fiddle..
    https://jsfiddle.net/huqozhqy/

where the gap between red boxes are lager than gap between green boxes.. i want a SASS mixin or maths formula to generate a grid where both gap is equal & fluid based on window resize..

HTML should be like this, no extra div..

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="span-4">
    <div class="span-2">1</div>
    <div class="span-2">1</div>
  </div
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: This is a pure CSS problem, Sass has nothing to do with it.

Comment: you can use display:inline-block or flex with text-align/justify-content and calc() to set width and to avoid margins http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/pvVBRj  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/QwrPKW

Comment: @PrajithSN links i proposed in my previous comment uses same html structure that you claim. your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/huqozhqy/3/ via inline-block and text-align method , for flex, look at my codepen

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use of sass... you could just nest two loops and have sass do the math...

scss

```
$columns: 4;
$subcolumns: 6;
$margin : 3%; 

@for $i from 1 through $columns {
  .span-#{$i} {
    width: (100 / $i) * 1% - $margin*(($i - 1)/$i);
    margin-right:$margin;

      @for $j from 1 through $subcolumns {
        .span-#{$j} {
          width: (100 / $j) * 1% - $i*$margin*(($j - 1)/$j);
          margin-right:$margin*$i;
        }
      }//j-loop

  }//i-loop

}

.col{
  float:left;
  background-color:maroon;
  .col{
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:10px;
    & .col:last-child{
      margin-right:0px;
    }
  }
}


.row{ 
  background-color:#999999;
  .col:last-child{
  margin-right:0px;
  }
  &:after{
   clear:both;
   content:"";
   display:block;
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col span-4">
      <div class="col span-2">2</div>
      <div class="col span-2">2</div>
</div>
<div class="col span-4">
      <div class="col span-2">2</div>
      <div class="col span-4">4</div>
      <div class="col span-4">4</div>
</div>

<div class="col span-2">
      <div class="col span-3">3</div>
      <div class="col span-6">6</div>
      <div class="col span-6">6</div>
      <div class="col span-3">3</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/johanthuresson/pen/NPMmox?editors=110

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But still, gaps not same especially when window resize!